# Defeated the bosses - what next?

Tags: terraria

I have a murderous cutlass that deals 64 melee damage, an Adenamite Drill, some magic stuff that tops 38 magic damage (Nimbus Rod) and 51 Defense. I've defeated Skeletron, the Eye of Cthulu and Brain of Cthulu more than once, the Wall of Flesh, Skeletron Prime, and the Destroyer.

I'm pretty sure that I have destroyed all of the demon altars in my world, but they didn't bless my world with titanium (which is pretty bad, considering that I can't progress in ores). So, what can I do next?

Comment: adamantite and titanium are the same thing. You'll wanna start doing hard mode stuff now that you've done the wall of flesh, like jungle and stuff. Then after plantera you unlock a whole lot more stuff

Comment: You need to kill the three mechanical bosses (Skeletron Prime, The Destroyer and The Twins) to make Plantera spawnable.

Comment: You could create a new savegame and go anouther round

Answer (score 5):

You could:

- Fight the Twins, the third hardmode boss.
- Explore the jungle to fight Plantera in hardmode and then enter the jungle temple.

There are new enemies that spawn inside the dungeon as well in hardmode, so you can go back and explore there as well as open the biome-specific chests inside.

Another thing to do is do quests for the fisherman or complete any achievements you may not have yet if you are playing on Steam. One last thing to try is to make a new world and set it to expert mode for the added challenge, and the expert-mode only loots.

Answer (score 1):

Your world can be blessed with 2 sets of ores , which sound and look different , but fullfill the same purpose. Same thing with the corruption and the crimson.

If you still want the ores , go fishing. They will eventually drop.

To progress you need to fight the twins in order to able to fight against Plantera in the jungle biome. To spawn plantera simply destroy one of the small pink bulbs.

After defeating Plantera you may open the chests in the dungeon using their specific key. (Corrupted chest e.g.)

If you drop a Temple key , you will have to find the Temple in the jungle biome.

After you defeated the Golem in the temple , the Lunatic cultist spawns at the Dungeon. If you manage to take him down , he will trigger the Lunar event.

The Lunar event is the final stage of Terraria.

More things to progress :

- Trigger a Solar Eclipse
- Trigger a Martian invasion (very hard)
- Trigger the Lunar event (very very hard , will trigger final boss afterwards)
- After beating the Lunar event , enter expert mode and do everything all over againg for more drops.